# Is it mandatory to install all DirectX versions for different games?

Tags: windows, directx

While installing the newest game of the Medal of Honor series, I got a strange DLL error saying that the game couldn't be launched.

When I installed DirectX 11, available as an installer, it worked.

Is it mandatory to install all the DirectX installers for subsequent different games?

Comment: You must install all the DirectX interfaces so that earlier games can use them, but not all the versions of the DirectX runtime itself -- just the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to install all the installer for DirectX for
>   subsequent different games?

Considering a game can use a specific date release of Direct X its always good to install the EXACT version the game expects.  There can be differences in the actual output of a method, if say there is a bug, and the developer adjusted their code to compensate for known behavior.

Comment: relevant http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=23759166&postcount=47

Comment: Due to the recent suspicious downvote I received to this answer decided to make it a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Game you are installing you have to at times install Direct X updates that has been happening for a long time and in every version of Windows.The only difference is the Direct x version its updated right now...

Hope this Helps...